# check password hash is not working in flask mysql

Tags: mysql, flask

I am creating a web app in flask and mysql. But the check hash password always returns error even if I know I am entering the correct password.

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/validateLogin',methods=['POST'])
def validateLogin():
    try:
        _username = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']
        cursor.callproc('sp_validateLogin',(_username,))
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        if len(data) > 0:
            if check_password_hash(str(data[0][3]),_password):
                session['user'] = data[0][0]
                return redirect('/userHome')
            else:
                return render_template('error.html',error = 'Wrong Email address or Password.')
        else:
            return render_template('error.html',error = 'Wrong Email address or Password.')
    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('error.html',error = str(e))
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

**Table description:**

```
user_id bigint  NO  PRI     auto_increment
user_name   varchar(45) YES         
user_username   varchar(45) YES         
user_password   varchar(200)    YES
```

**Validate login procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_validateLogin`(
IN p_username VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    select * from tbl_user where user_username = p_username;
END
```

Comment: could someone please help me with it ? what am I doing wrong here ? why is the check hash password not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/validateLogin',methods=['GET','POST'])
def validateLogin():
try:
    _username = request.form['inputEmail']
    _password = request.form['inputPassword']
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select user_password, user_id from tbl_user where user_username = %s', (_username))
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in data:
        hashed_password = ("%s" % (row["user_password"]))
        userid = ("%s" % (row["user_id"]))

    if len(data) > 0:
        if check_password_hash(hashed_password,_password):
            session['user'] = userid
            return redirect('/userHome')
        else:
            return render_template('error.html',error = 'Wrong Email address or Password.')
    else:
        return render_template('error.html',error = 'Wrong Email address or Password.')
except Exception as e:
    return render_template('error.html',error = str(e))
finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).